# How to read in different sized variables from binary file in C++?

Tags: c++, file, binaryfiles

I'm reading in 7 things from the binary file all of which contain different known sizes which I have labelled under variables with their respective variable type and sizes in bytes. How do I read these in one after the other, I keep getting segmentation faults.

Here is the code:

```
ifstream file;
file.open(fileName, ios::in | ios::binary);

// Variables
char *process_name;      // 16 bytes (string)
int process_id;          // 4 bytes
char activity_status;    // 1 bytes
int cpu_burst_time;      // 4 bytes
int base_register;       // 4 bytes
long int limit_register; // 8 bytes
char priority;           // 1 byte

// Process Name
string s;
file.read((char *) &s, 16);

// then process ID, activity status, etc.

file.close();
```

Let me know if I should add more details or code. I may have made a mistake with any of the variable types so correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `(char *) &s` What do you think this means?

Comment: Casting the string to a char? Not really sure that's why I'm here.

Comment: Casting things when you don't know is what makes things go boom. Don't cast things before you understand what it means.

Comment: You can't read string objects like this. A string may contain 16 chars, but is not reductible to.

Comment: It's ok to `reinterpret_cast` a built-in variable to a pointer and hand it over to `read`. Doing it with a `std::string` will not work.

Comment: `std::string` isn't like a primitive (or "trivial") data type.  It's got a control block containing the current length, current maximum capacity, and some storage that can either be the characters (when short enough) or a pointer to the characters on the heap (when the string is too long to fit locally).  If you know it's 16 bytes you need, an alternative is to create a `char[16]`, read into that, then initialize your std::string from that buffer.

Comment: @Perette Would doing something like this work?
`char data[16];`
`file.read(data, 16);`
`printf("%s ", data);`
It's printing out 0

Comment: That's better yes. `char data[17] {};` to be sure it's null-terminated.

Comment: C++ is not C, so please don't include C as a tag, because you will only annoy people like me.